# How can I bind multiple values from array in v-model for form-input on vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I need to show full address in one form-input with buttons 'Edit' and 'Delete', so it's working, but in browser console I have error for all addresses like this

'[Vue warn]: Error in event handler for "input": "TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'zip' in 'Country Name', 'City', 'Street Address', [object Object]"'

My vue code:

```
<template>
<div>
....
</div>
...
        <form class="form-inline" >
            <div class="form-row col-md-6" v-for="address in addressList">
                <b-form-group>
                    <b-form-input class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" id="address.id" v-model="address.countryName + ', ' + address.city + ', ' + address.streetAddress + ', ' + address.zip" />
                </b-form-group>
                <div class="btn-group mr-2" role="group">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary mb-2">Edit</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary mb-2">Delete</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </b-form>
</div>
</template>

<script>
...
    data() {
        return {
            addressList: [],
        }
    },

    async beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
        next(async (c) => await c.initData());
    },

    methods: {
        async initData() {
            await this.loadAddressList();
        },

        async loadAddressList() {
            this.addressList = await accountService.getAddressList();
        },
    }
}
</script>
```

I don't understand why I am getting this error but it's working. Is there another better solution for this? And without error?

```
v-model="address.countryName + ', ' + address.city + ', ' + address.streetAddress + ', ' + address.zip"
```

Comment: Can you show what `addressList` might look like once it's filled with data?

Comment: @T.Dirks Yes, https://imgur.com/a/KT9wAps

Comment: Sorry, I meant what it might look like data wise. Can you show a `console.log` of `addressList`?

Comment: @T.Dirks You mean this? https://imgur.com/a/prF1fPw

Comment: `v-model` is supposed to be used with a single variable. You should use separate inputs for each variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your problem lays with binding the `v-model`. How you have it, it binds/concats multiple variables which isn't the intended use for `v-modal`.

If you only want to display the value, you could try changing:

```
v-model="address.countryName + ', ' + address.city + ', ' + address.streetAddress + ', ' + address.zip"
```

to

```
:value="address.countryName + ', ' + address.city + ', ' + address.streetAddress + ', ' + address.zip"
```